# \copy No such file or directory even though the file exists

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to copy some data to a csv file via psql's `\copy` command.

The command i'm trying to use is

```
\copy (
<some query here>
) to '/Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv' delimiter ',' with csv;
```

and the error i'm getting is:

```
/Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv: No such file or directory
```

I verified the file exists and is writable.

```
ls -al /Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcaflisch  staff  0 Jul 10 13:58 /Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv
```

If I change to `...to '/tmp/tasks_data.csv' delimiter ',' with csv;

I instead get the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ... and t.run_id = r.run_id ) TO STDOUT delimiter ',' with csv;
```

Comment: Does it work with a different filename?  Do you have the existing .csv file open in a spreadsheet program?

Comment: I do not have it open and it doesn't not work with a different file name.

Answer (score 1):

Well the syntax error is due to this:

```
to '/Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv' delimiter ',' with csv;

--It should be:

to '/Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv' WITH delimiter ',' csv;

--Or the new style:

to '/Users/tomcaflisch/Downloads/tasks_data.csv' WITH (delimiter ',', format csv);
```

Try with fixed version to see if it works with /tmp file then /users/* file. If does not work with /Users/* file then crawl up the path to see if there is something wrong with permissions at each level of directory.

Comment: I tried all of those. It seemed that it was due to newline chars.